# Consolidation of the Earth's Governments into Superstates

Tags: politics, government

In a scenario I am presently working on, the Earth has been unified into three [1] large nations that each span ridiculous amounts of territory. Now, as I am *incredibly* ignorant in the area of politics, I have placed the following areas into consolidated power;

- North and South America
- All of Russia and most of Europe
- All of Eastern Asia and Oceania

In this scenario it is necessary for **every** state to be capable of advanced space travel, and for the world to have a very interconnected and interdependent economy. The problem I have run into is *how* to logically unite the governments into larger states, as well as what to do with the largely set-back (in terms of economics and spaceflight) nations of Africa.

So, the questions are;

- Which nations would unify and become large states, and what circumstances would cause them to do this (no stipulations here, really. War? Diplomacy? Disease?)?
- What is a logical way to either assume the majority of Africa into another nation, or boost them into a higher position of prosperity and wealth?

Factors to keep in mind-

- The present date is anywhere from 2100-2250 AD.
- The story is largely hard science-fiction based. No spaghetti monsters.
- The world population has grown (roughly) as projected.
- The states are in a space race of sorts.

I hope I asked this question in an agreeable format- if not, please tell me and I will do everything in my power to change it to your liking.

[1] This number is subject to change, I'm not entirely set on it being three, but too many more would seem a bit too much, and two would seem too small. Feel free to play with the exact amount if you like.

Comment: We have always been at war with Eastasia.

Comment: @CortAmmon Sorry?

Comment: Its a reference to 1984

Comment: That reference was double-plus good.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for clarifying, I have not read 1984 yet.

Comment: @gladiens you may find it interesting to look at - take that world, and ask what happens if peace comes...

Comment: Japanese anime love these kind of "three kingdoms", you got the world split up in Code Geass and the world split up in Gundam 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the following Mega-States

1. European Union (Europe and Russia)
2. America (North and South America)
3. Asia-Pacific (East Asia and Oceania)
4. Africa (Africa and Middle-East)

For its formation I'll give the guidelines that made me imagine such division.

The European Union simply consolidates as it is now. Countries become more economically and politically dependant. At certain point international organisms have such power that we no longer speak of independent states and all European Union becomes a Mega-State.

Meanwhile China continued expanding. Making all Asia-Pacific dependant on China's economy soon they all became a single Mega-State too. I can imagine some wars there, but mainly with non-democratic countries. The democratic ones would join China through treaties, and having a specific status in the Mega-State.

Having these two big competitors, USA would try to reinforce their relations with south-american countries. Through treaties, some economic pressure and bribery they would create the USNSA (United States of North and South America).

Africa as a Mega-State would be created differently. With three Mega-States, Africa would become the next target. Oil and land to exploit would make it somewhat interesting again to colonize. The three Mega-States would agree not to begin a war for Africa, specially due to how related were their economies (as it is now). Middle-East would use this opportunity to create a land for Islam.

China, America and Asia wouldn't want to stop Islam to invade Africa for avoiding a war between them: As soon as one goes there, it's clear for the other two competitors that as soon as war ends he'll have access to Africa's resources freely.

Comment: I think it would just stay the United States of America. Perhaps America finally got tired of illegal immigrants, which helped spur them to start their campaign, coupled with the other pressures you mentioned.

Comment: @Alber Masclans Thank you very much for your post! I have been reading Journeyman Geek and your posts over and over all day, and cannot decide which I like more- but, I think that that's fine, as my question has been answered. Since you both did such wonderful jobs, I don't really think I should accept either of your answers (I wish I could accept both)- but keep in mind that I am immensely grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than separation, it would be consolidation. In a way there's a few real world analogs that might be a useful starting point. Rather than superstates, this would be confederations of mutual self interest.

The EU is already in a bit of a period of political and military unity and spreading outwards peacefully. Eastern Europe's been wavering between russian and european spheres of influence and this might bring them into conflict with the Russians. Give them an ultra nationalist government which loses the war and their opponents might *partially* ally with Europe. In an attempt to 'help' an old ally, the Chinese might invade the far east forming a second superstate.

A militarily strong china would be scary for much of Asia, and they might band together to form a third superstate. A loose "Asian Confederation" of sorts.

Now, Britain might not want to be part of the great european commonwealth. They might ally with the US, and Canada forming an atlantic alliance, along with former british colonies and maybe bits of Russia. Australia and New Zealand feel like a natural cultural fit here.

That leaves South America and Africa There's probably parts of Russia at this point that still believe on socialism and they flee. Starting at places with natural inclinations towards socialism, say Venezuela, Bolivia and  Angolan, they unify into a new 'USSR', and invade and retake chunks of old Russia.

The middle east has run out of oil and is kind of unimportant. Its a land of dust general unimportance. No one cares particularly about it outside being neutral ground, and some tourism. Its probably the place where intrigue.

So, why socialism for South America and Africa? They're resource rich, industry poor. And while communism is a terrible idea, it was made worse by *people*. Have resources controlled centrally by computers and it just might work. It would also allow for the 'state' to centrally manage industrialisation and to kickstart their economies. A 'natural' rivalry between them and the 'Atlantic Alliance' due to the russian and south american elements, and the african elements being courted by china would be handy too.

The expanded chinese government might not be the communist party at that point, but would be sandwiched between European Russia, and an american buffer zone. They can't retreat due to strategic reasons, but its an uneasy territory. Getting invaded by the new USSR might be a interesting way to move the story, especially if you have a 4 way cold war.

The asian confederation is sort of neutral. Unlike the other states, they have no natural enemy (other than the Chinese, who are busy with the Atlantics, Europeans, and Soviets), and are kind of following their own agendas. The Indians and Pakistanis don't quite get along, ASEAN has been their own little club and wants better economic ties with everyone, the Japanese are still wavering between pacifism and hitting the Chinese pretty hard when they aren't looking, and so on.

I'd like to think the atlantic alliance is isolationist as far as terran affairs go, but they're trying to beat everyone, since they've had a lot of experience in space.

Of course? Why? We're out of oil of course. helium 3 on other planets! Martian Iron Mining! Massive space platforms! Other cool things! Space battles!

Comment: Britain? You mean Airstrip One?

Comment: ._. I totally was not thinking of judge dread. I was actually thinking of the GITS universe, with the americans in a dirty war in south america

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Hey Journeyman Geek, thank you *very* much for your post! Both you and Albert Masclans have done wonderful jobs providing an answer to my question, and I am working on combining them in a cohesive way. As both of you did so well, I will not be accepting any question using the system, but I would like you to know that I am grateful nevertheless.

Comment: The system gets cranky and bumps up questions with no selected answer all the time. Considering there's very rarely a 'perfect' answer here, I strongly suggest picking one, even if its the other guy's.

Comment: Bumping up as in pushing them to the top of the boards?

Comment: Yup. Which can be a bit annoying.

Comment: Alrighty- I will do that!